# Create Pyinstaller app on Docker running Mac

Tags: python, docker, macos, pyinstaller

I try to create a standalone python app using Pyinstaller which should run and can be reproducibly recreated on Windows, Linux, and Mac.
The idea is to use Docker to have a fixed environment that creates the app and exports it again. For Linux and Windows, I could make it work using https://github.com/cdrx/docker-pyinstaller.

the idea is to let docker create a fully functioning pyinstaller app (with GUI) within and export this app. Since pyinstaller depends on the package versions etc. this should be fixed in the docker and only the new source code should be supplied to compile and export a new version of the software.

in the ideal scenario (and how it already works with Linux and Windows), the user can create the docker and compile the software itself:

```
docker build -t docker_pyinstaller_linux https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loipf/calimera_docker_export/main/linux/Dockerfile

docker run --rm -v "/path/to/app_source_code:/code/" -v "${PWD}:/code/dist/" docker_pyinstaller_linux
```

---

For Mac, however, there is no simple straightforward solution. There is one Mac docker image out there https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX, but the docker creation code is not that simple.

my idea:

1. take https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX/blob/master/Dockerfile.auto
2. add to the end the download of miniconda:

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /Users/user

### install miniconda to /miniconda
RUN curl -LO "http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.4.10-MacOSX-x86_64.sh"
RUN bash Miniconda3-4.4.10-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -p /miniconda -b
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:${PATH}
RUN conda update -y conda

### install packages from conda 
RUN conda install -c anaconda -y python=3.8
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pyqt5
...
```

but already the first command fails due to `chmod: cannot access '/Users/user': No such file or directory` since I am in a different "environment" than the interactive session (`/home/arch/OSX-KVM`). Can somebody help me out?

I know these asking for code pieces questions are not the best, and I could show you all the things I tried, but I doubt they will help anybody. I would like to have a minimum Mac example without user login or gui etc (which should be possible using https://github.com/sickcodes/osx-optimizer). It should only have miniconda installed (with pyinstaller and a few packages).

---

other info:
I can run the previous commands in the mac environment interactively in the docker environment but would like to fix these commands permanently in the image:

```
docker pull sickcodes/docker-osx:auto    ### replace with docker with pyinstaller and packages
docker run -it \
    --device /dev/kvm \
    -p 50922:10022 \
    sickcodes/docker-osx:auto
```

ideally in the end, we can run the above command with OSX_commands `pyinstaller file.spec`

---

---

related questions but without solution:

- [Using Docker and Pyinstaller to distribute my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589353/using-docker-and-pyinstaller-to-distribute-my-application)
- [How to create OS X app with Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772216/how-to-create-os-x-app-with-python-on-windows/65499598#65499598)

Comment: Python is preinstalled on two of the three operating systems you list; Docker won't be installed by default on any of them without the end user manually installing it.  Would distributing a native Python package work better?  If this process worked perfectly, what would you put into it and what would come out

Comment: I edited the question and made my point and idea clearer, hopefully this helps.

if it works perfectly (like for Linux and Windows) you supply the new source code to the docker. The docker runs pyinstaller internally and exports a running software back to the original environment (see added code piece in question)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but starting off from `batonogov/docker-pyinstaller`. I'm currently stuck with installing `homebrew` to install a decent verison of `python`, but I managed to overcome a first issue akin to yours by adding `USER root` to the Dockerfile - seems not to be the default

Answer (score 0):

Please consider [this new mac image for docker-pyinstaller](https://hub.docker.com/r/batonogov/pyinstaller-osx), combining the base image identified by you and the docker-pyinstaller version maintained at [batonogov/docker-pyinstaller](https://github.com/batonogov/docker-pyinstaller).